# rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment

Tags: postgis, raster, coordinate-system, gdal, postgresql

I have a set of geometries in my database which I used to create a set of rasters (each raster has a unique color). Now I would like to merge all of these rasters  into one but get an error such as :

```
rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment
```

I tried to resample all of these rasters using ST_Resample(geometry_set, 800, 600) methods but it does not help me.

The numbers 800 and 600 are the width and height values used to generate rasters.

How could I merge all of these rasters into one?

Here is my PostgreSQL script:

```
SELECT
        layer."SummaryId",        
        layer."Name",
        encode(
            ST_AsPNG(
                ST_Union(layer.raster)   
            ),
            'base64'        
        ) AS pngBase64String       
 FROM     

(
  SELECT 
    s."Id" AS "SummaryId", 
    r."Name" AS "Name", 

            ST_ColorMap(                    
              ST_AsRaster( 
                  ST_MakeValid (                
                      ST_GeomFromText("WktString", 4326)            
                  ), 
                  800, 
                  600
                ),
                1,     
                mr."ColorMap"
          --)
       ) AS raster

  FROM "TableA" AS s        
  INNER JOIN "TableB" AS r ON r."Id" = s."SomeId"        
  INNER JOIN "TableC" AS l ON l."TableAId" = s."Id"        
  INNER JOIN "TableD" AS mr ON mr."Id" = l."RangeId"
  WHERE 
    s."StartDate" >= '2018-09-10 00:00:00' AND  
    s."EndDate" <= '2018-09-10 23:59:59'   

  GROUP BY s."Id", r."Name", l."WktString", mr."ColorMap"

) AS layer

GROUP BY 
  layer."SummaryId",
  layer."Name"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution @Tequila?